# Widget not registering with Android System

Tags: android, widget

I am trying to add a widget to the home screen that allows users to view some database information.  Unfortunately it seems that i cannot get the widget to register with my Android system.

Here is the manifest file:

```
<reciever android:name="com.Money.EasyMoney.FreeCashWidget"
              android:label="Free Cash Widget 4x1"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>

            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider"
                       android:resource="@xml/freecashwidget"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </reciever>

</application>
```

Here is the widget-provider in res/xml/freecashwidget.xml

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:minWidth="294dp"
                android:minHeight="72dp"
                android:minResizeHeight="72dp"
                android:minResizeWidth="294dp"

                android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
                android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:initialLayout="@layout/freecashwidget"
                android:resizeMode="none">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="294dp"
          android:layout_height="72dp"
          android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Free Cash:"
            android:id="@+id/textWidgetFreeCash"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonRecordExpense"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_spend"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the receiver:

```
public class FreeCashWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
{
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager AppManager, int[] widgets)
{
    super.onUpdate(context, AppManager, widgets);
    final int n = widgets.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int widgetid = widgets[i];

        //create an intent to launch the specified activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, main.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        //get the layout and attach an onclicklistener for the button
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.freecashwidget);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonRecordExpense, pIntent);

        //tell the app widget manager to perform an update ont eh current app widget
        AppManager.updateAppWidget(widgetid, view);
    }
}
}
```

Its just a text box with a button that's supposed to be 4x1 and is being added directly into my app.  I've tried rebooting the device.  I am stumped on this one.

EDIT:

Once I run this it should just register the widget correct?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my samsung galaxy s3. Try to set Your app icon from the app drawer to the homescreen. After I had done this, the widgets from my app appeared...

Comment: Thanks, but no cigar.  I'm not sure what i'm missing.

Comment: Can you try with setting `android:updatePeriodMillis` to some value other than zero like `180000`, thats 30 minutes.

Comment: <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:minWidth="294dp"
                    android:minHeight="72dp"
                    android:minResizeHeight="72dp"
                    android:minResizeWidth="294dp"
                    android:updatePeriodMillis="180000"
                    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:initialLayout="@layout/freecashwidget"
                    android:resizeMode="horizontal">
</appwidget-provider>
This didn't work.